# Unable to add custom domain to Firebase hosting - already be registered to another project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

- I deleted a Google Cloud Platform project and created a brand new project.
- I never deregistered the custom domain that I assigned to the old project.
- When I try to assign the new domain in Firebase hosting I can't because I get the following error message

```
Unable to add domain. It may already be registered to another project.
```

[image: Add a custom domain in Firebase hosting]

*Note that **mydomain.com** is just a placeholder in the screenshot above.*

Answer (score 1):

If the project is pending deletion, it can be restored and the resources can be deallocated. The project can then be deleted again.